# Can Fortran be forced to abide by the order of arguments in a logical operation?

Tags: fortran

I am looping through indices and I am checking if I am not in the first loop interation and another condition. I don't want the second condition to be evaluated if the first is `.False.`.

```
do i = 1, n
    if ( i /= 1 .and. var(i) > var(i-1) ) then
        do something
    end if
end do
```

Clearly in this scenario, evaluating the second condition if the first condition is false will lead to an index error. Since if `i = 0` then `var(i-1)` will be below the lower bounds.

Why is the second condition evaluated if the first is already `.False.`? Is there a way to avoid this without create a second `if` statement?

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but the answer's here somewhere - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607448/order-of-logical-operations-potential-ifort-bug/35607732

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest answer is 'no'.  For the code shown, you have two option

```
do i = 1, n
   if ( i /= 1 ) then
      if (var(i) > var(i-1) ) then
         do something
      end if
   end if
end do
```

or

```
do i = 2, n
   if (var(i) > var(i-1) ) then
      do something
   end if
end do
```

Answer (score 4):

Fortran currently does not allow safe use of the form of the question: a compiler is free to evaluate all operands of an expression if it chooses and such operands in the program must conform to the requirements of the standard. A compiler is allowed *not to* evaluate the `var(i) > var(i-1)` operand when the `i /= 1` operand evaluates as false (Fortran 2018, 10.1.7):

> It is not necessary for a processor to evaluate all of the operands of an expression, or to evaluate entirely each operand, if the value of the expression can be determined otherwise.

This does not, however, give the programmer licence to assume the compiler will skip an evaluation, or will evaluate in a particular order.

We can see this clearly in the deliberations of the Fortran standards committee. There has been over time proposals to introduce such things as the [`.andthen.` and `.orelse.`](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-239.txt) operators motivated by the similar case:

> The poster-child use-case is something like
>
> if( I <= NMAX .and. A(I) > 0.0 )then
>
> where the intention is to evaluate A(I) only when I is in-bounds.

So far such proposals have not made it in to the language (F2018 standard or F2023 draft), but most recently this has been noted as [worthy of ongoing consideration](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/21/21-194.txt).

[steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75312595/3157076) shows how the case of the question can be safely written in the absence of these or similar operators.

Answer (score 1):

***Note:** the striked text below results from a wild interpretation of the standard, which is probably wrong, so I have edited these parts. As a matter of fact, in the example with the `foo()` function the Intel compiler never skips the evaluation of `foo(c)==0`, but gfortran does skip it whenever possible and when compiling with `-O3`)*

---

In Fortran something like `expr1 .and. expr2` is considered as a single expression that has to be fully evaluated. As in any expression the compiler is free to evaluate the sub-expressions in any order. It is also free to not evaluate one of the sub-expressions <s>, **as long as it has no side-effect** compared to a complete evaluation</s> (*edited: if it not necessary*).

It means that in `(i /= 1) .and. (var(i) > var(i-1))`, the compiler is free **(but not required to)** skip the evaluation of `(var(i) > var(i-1))` if it has already evaluated `(i /= 1)` to false (i.e. `i is equal to 1).

However if you have `(i /= 1) .and. (foo(c) == 0))` with `foo()` being a function that can modify `c`, e.g.

```
integer function foo(counter)
integer, intent(inout) :: counter
foo = mod(counter,10)
counter = counter + 1
end function
```

<s>Then the compiler is **required** to evaluate `foo(c) == 0`, whichever the evaluation of `(i /= 1)` (note that it could possibly skip the evaluation of `(i /= 1)`, though)</s>. (*edited: this is actually the same as above, the compiler may (but again is not required to) skip the evaluation of `foo(c) == 0`, meaning the the value of `c` may get undefined*).

In C `expr1 && expr2` is not really an expression, one could rather see it as a construct with specific rules for the evaluation of the expressions.

Comment: Learned something new today, and I have been using Fortran for 20 years. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think `(i /= 1) .and. (foo(c) == 0))` always requires the evaluation of `foo(c)`? When `i==1`, `c` becomes undefined after that expression is evaluated, and the function itself need not be evaluated. As the standard says: "It is not necessary for a processor to evaluate all of the operands of an expression, or to evaluate entirely each
operand, if the value of the expression can be determined otherwise." The expression is fully determined to be false when `i==1` is true.

Comment: @francescalus I have seen this debate in the past, and some people had a wide (or maybe wild) interpretation of "the value of the expression", which was including the side effects. I admit it was just an interpretation, though.

Comment: "An expression represents either a data object reference or a computation, and its value is either a scalar or an array. Evaluation of an expression produces a value, which has a type, type parameters (if appropriate), and a shape" doesn't seem to me to support an interpretation where "side effects" are part of the expression's value, but if you can add some supporting evidence to your answer I'd consider that a valuable contribution.

Comment: I agree that this interpretation looks wild, and that I am probably wrong. I will edit my answer. IIRC some people were doing this interpretation because some compilers were not skipping the evaluations in this kind of situation. And as a matter of fact ifort still doesn't (even if compiling with -O3): one can wonder why such an obvious optimization is not applied (one answer can be that the Intel engineers agree with the wild interpretation, but I agree this is not the only possible explanation).

Comment: This topic is perhaps much closer being a question in its own right. One item of note though is that a reference to the `foo` here has no effect that is observable outside the expression's evaluation (cf., having an output statement). You can't ask what value `c` has after the expression has been evaluated so at a purely Fortran level you can't tell whether or not the function was actually executed.